# Pandas plotting: ValueError: ordinal should be >= 1

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following Series, called `sr`.

```
In [1]: sr
Out[1]: 0     0
        1     0
        2     0
        3     0
        4     0
        5     1
        6     2
        7     4
        8     7
        9     4
        10    3
        11    2
        12    1
        13    2
        14    2
        15    2
        16    4
        17    7
        18    7
        19    5
        20    3
        21    2
        22    1
        23    1
        dtype: int64
```

I would like to plot this Series, together with the rolling mean. For this, I use the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

rolling = pd.rolling_mean(sr, 3, center=True)
ax_delays = sr.plot(style='--', color='b')
rolling.plot(color='b', ax=ax_delays, legend=0)
plt.title('Title')
plt.ylim(ymax=10)
plt.show()
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
      1 rolling = pd.rolling_mean(sr, 3, center=True)
----> 2 ax_delays = sr.plot(style='--', color='b')
      3 rolling.plot(color='b', ax=ax_delays, legend=0)
      4 plt.title('Title')
      5 plt.ylim(ymax=10)

ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1
```

What does this error mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: This works for me, what version pandas are you running? I'm using 0.16.0

Comment: Yes, I am using pandas 0.16.0 too. Maybe restarting IPython Notebook works.

Comment: Can you show the output of `sr.index`?

Comment: `sr.index` gives me `Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23], dtype='int64')`

Comment: Strange, that looks OK. Can you provide a small reproducible example? (the code to generate some data that reproduces the problem)

Comment: I restarted my IPython notebook and it worked without hesitating. Strange indeed.

Comment: This happened to me too as follows:
I had done some plotting at one point with plt. Then, I used the same plt handle to plot on top of a figure which used some particular axis labeling. I got the exact same error as you (always when trying to plot a rolling average). So maybe you had been plotting something else with plt and re-used the plt handle?

Answer (score 4):

If you run `plt.clf()` this will clear the plot in memory and may allow the plotting to proceed (worked for me when I encountered this error after interrupting the plotting routine).